# Cannot log in through gui X-server broken

Tags: 13.10, ati, login-screen, xserver, gpu-driver

I recently installed fglrx after using the open source drivers(without any problems) when restarting gave me black screen I tried everything then decided to un-install the drivers and reinstall open-source drivers but the problem persisted. I then tried the following but still nothing changed.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge xorg-driver-fglrx fglrx*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update -f
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

I did notice that i can log in as guest in the splash screen.
I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 and kernel 3.12 on a laptop with switchable graphics. I'm only using unity.
Inisde tty console I get the following.

```
glxinfo
Error: unable to open display
```

However in guest session it displays normal values

Answer (score 1):

Looking at my `.Xsession-errors` file, I found that my home folder's permissions had been changed somehow. I changed it back to

```
drwxr-xr-x me me
```

and now it works again.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get out of there is to get out of this situation is to get to a recovery console.

Hold Shift key on boot up.

Once you are on the GRUB menu, choose a recovery mode. Then, choose a root console.

Once you manage to get to a recovery console as root:

apt-get autoremove fglrx

reboot

[this is where I found this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/411564/black-screen-after-installing-gflrx-on-ubuntu-13-10)